# Update list with new element from persist object

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have fetched one object from database by using Hibernate and trying to add child object in list, But it shows that "parent key not found" error. Here is my Hibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.demo.hibernate.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">

        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"></property>
        <property name="edu" column="edu" type="string"></property>
        <list name="lstAddress" cascade="all">
            <key column="EMPLOYEE_ID" />
            <list-index column="id" />
            <one-to-many class="com.demo.hibernate.Address" />
        </list>
    </class>

    <class name="com.demo.hibernate.Address" table="ADDRESS">

        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="city" column="city" type="string"></property>
        <property name="state" column="state" type="string"></property>
        <many-to-one name="objEmployee" column="employee_id" class="com.demo.hibernate.Address" />
    </class>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Java Code

```
Employee objEmployee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, 1);
Address objAdd = new Address();
objAdd.setId(200);
objAdd.setCity("Mumbai");
objAdd.setState("Maharashtra");
objAdd.setObjEmployee(objEmployee);
objEmployee.getLstAddress().add(objAdd);

session.saveOrUpdate(objEmployee);
```

And here is the exception which I received

```
8180 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
8180 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HIBERNATE_MAP.FKE66327D438D94246) violated - parent key not found

8180 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
8180 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HIBERNATE_MAP.FKE66327D438D94246) violated - parent key not found

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HIBERNATE_MAP.FKE66327D438D94246) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:459)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
```

Is I am doing any wrong configurations? Guid me if any one faced this kind of issue.

Comment: Either disable Foreign key constraint HIBERNATE_MAP.FKE66327D438D94246, or ensure that you inserted parent record first

Comment: Parent record is alreday there. I am just fetching it and trying to add new element in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
Employee objEmployee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, 1);
Address objAdd = new Address();
objAdd.setId(200);
objAdd.setCity("Mumbai");
objAdd.setState("Maharashtra");
objAdd.setObjEmployee(objEmployee);
//objEmployee.getLstAddress().add(objAdd);
// save objAdd not objEmployee
session.saveOrUpdate(objAdd);
```

Comment: No. Same exception. I just changed `<generator class="assigned" />` to `<generator class="increment" />` for `Address` class and saved `objAdd` and `objEmployee` objects which works fine. Can't we add new element in list when generator class is `assigned`?

Comment: please try persist instead of saveOrUpdate method, and put generator class="assigned"